# Word for a person or group who is actively preventing the progress of another person or group

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to come up with a word that describes when one person or group is actively trying to prevent the progress of another person or group but more specifically when the actions they are  preventing would be beneficial to both parties.

Thanks.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obstructionist. [dictionary.com reference](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/obstructionist)

Answer (score 0):

How about "intervention" for the action; "interventionist" for the person or group? While "obstructionist" or "obstructionism" *could* be used, IMO that is more indicative of someone or some action that is antagonistic and more one-sided. Not, as you indicate, an action or a person's/group's action that would be beneficial for **both** parties.

An intervention is more likely pursued for mutual benefit.